# Jumbichū or Junbichū for じゅんびちゅう, Konban wa or Komban wa for こんばんは？

Tags: rōmaji

Can someone give me some advice. In some text books I see N used and in some I see M used for ん and in a dictionary I see them using n with a line above it.

I assume this is because of the way the words appear in Romaji but would like some advice as I am getting a bit confused and in particular the dictionary where an n appears with a line above.

Comment: By the way, the word *konbanwa* is standardly spelled こんばんは rather than こんばんわ, although you might see the latter on the internet sometimes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways to romanize Japanese, and each one is based on different principles.  Some try to represent the phonemes of the language; some try to represent the phonetics (actual pronunciation); others try to represent the way a word is written in Japanese orthography, or the way a word is typed into a Japanese computer.

One scheme, called Traditional Hepburn, changes the spelling of ん based on the following consonant.  Why?  Because the pronunciation of ん depends on the phonetic context it appears in, and James Curtis Hepburn wanted to convey some of these phonetic details in his romanization scheme.  Because ん is pronounced [m] before /b/, こんばんは is spelled *kombanwa* in that scheme.

One problem that comes up in romanization is how to distinguish between んい and に.  If you write ん as *n*, they'll both end up looking like *ni*, and you won't be able to distinguish words like かんい and かに.  Different romanization schemes solve this problem in different ways.  The dictionary you're looking at uses the line over n to distinguish the two, so かんい and かに are *kan̄i* and *kani* respectively.  Another dictionary might write *kan'i* and *kani* to distinguish the two.

In any case, the word is the same and is pronounced the same way.  These are just minor differences in how the word is romanized.

Comment: I'm not sure if the line over the 'n' in *kan̄i* will show up properly for everyone, but I hope the answer is still understandable even if it looks strange.

Comment: For a word like good evening when pronounced in Japanese would you suggest I try to pronounce that as though there was a "m" or a "n" ?  Thanks

Comment: Your line over the n did show up for me.  I'm wondering, did you enter this using an English keyboard as I am not sure how to enter than when using an Apple keyboard

Comment: @Alan You would pronounce the first ん in こんばんは as an [m] sound: http://forvo.com/word/%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%B0%E3%82%93%E3%81%AF/#ja