# Why do people romanize 新聞 as "Shimbun"?

Tags: nuances, rōmaji

Is there a reason why [新聞]{しんぶん} is often romanized as "Shimbun" instead of the "Shinbun" its supposed to be? I ask as I've found that even brands like 毎日新聞 do this; romanizing their name as "Mainichi Shimbun".

How did this all start? And is it actually the correct romanization? Or is it just a miss-romanization that people've just gone with?

Comment: Also https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39865/11104

Comment: Holy shizzles I learned a thing!